# Sticky secondary scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

First of all, I know that `position: sticky` exists. I'm not trying to create a sticky header or menu; I'm trying to create a **sticky scrollbar**.

### Problem

I have a narrow container that contains nicely formatted data and sometimes contains wide tables. I have no control over the tables' content, number of columns/rows, or the width of the parent container.

To show the content of the table, normally one would **add a horizontal scrollbar to the whole container** and call it a day. The problem with this approach is that after scrolling right, other children of this container would be shifted left, making them invisible.

So the logical next idea is to **add a scrollbar to each table**. It works very well for short tables, but as soon as you stumble upon a tall one, the horizontal scrollbar is nowhere to be seen. You'd have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the table, scroll right, and then scroll back up to see what you missed.

What I thought of is **a scrollbar that would appear when it's needed, and disappear when the wide table is no longer visible**. Since there can be multiple tables in the container, each would need to have a horizontal scrollbar stuck to it.

### Question

Putting aside the story above, including the concept of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) – how would one implement something like this?

[image: Animated GIF showing a sticky secondary scrollbar]

I thought of the following solution:

- Monitor the position of the table in the container
- When more than 20 px of the table is visible, attach a transparent floating div to its bottom
- If the div is not fully "visible" in the container, move it up so it is
- Set that div's width to match the wide table, so it has a scrollbar
- Control the table's position using that div's scrollbar

It feels incredibly hacky and prone to errors, though. Is there another approach that would work reliably?

Comment: This does sound like a very good idea, and a truly nice UX design IMO. As you mentioned yourself, this also looks tricky to implement, to say the least. However on Stackoverflow we're not supposed to develop whole solutions like this and write all the code from scratch for you (Well I could but you'd have to hire me haha) You're supposed to try it yourself, and then we can help if you're stuck at a particular step.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm aware that implementing this from scratch would be time-consuming, especially including testing if it doesn't break in edge cases. I'm not really looking for a complete solution, only for ideas how to approach this problem, as I could be missing something obvious.